# OpenOffice: Set as default for all users

Tags: windows-7, openoffice.org, file-association

In our office we have shared workspaces (many people can sit at the same computer).  We are using OpenOffice and each time a person sits at a station for the first time I have to associate the documents (Word, Excel, etc.) with OpenOffice.

Is there a way to automatically associate OpenOffice with the documents for any user that sits at these stations?

We are using Windows 7 Professional.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried as administrator to set file association ?

```
As Admin, Open Control Panel > Control Panel Home  > Default Programs > Set Associations.     
Select a file type in the list and click Change Program.
```